# How To? django model field whose value is a choice of a manytomany field of the same model

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I have a django model called company with a manytomany field where company members are added.

I have another field, called 'company_contact' where I want to be able to choose from one of the company_members as if it was a ForeingKey to company_members.
Is there an easy way of doing this without customized forms, ajax request, django-autocomplete-light, etc?

I intend to fill this model using django admin.
Thanks

```
class Dm_Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, verbose_name="Razon Social")
    company_members = models.ManyToManyField(conf_settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name="Miembros")
    #company_contact = models.ForeignKey(conf_settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="company_members", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_phone = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, verbose_name="Telefono compania")
    company_email = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, verbose_name="Email compania")
```

Comment: But what do you mean ?, do you want to choose in company_contact only one member of the Auth User model extracted from the company_members field?

Comment: @jsanchezs exactly. I need to choose only one user that belongs to company_members

Comment: Why is different company_members field from company_contact ?, you can just use one field that covers it in the first selection, if they're different then it will be the same field setting for company_contact as in company_members

Comment: Company_contact is only one of company_members. Company_members can be many

Answer (score 0):

The one way that I can think of would be to use a ManyToMany with a through model.

```
class Dm_Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, verbose_name="Razon Social")
    company_members = models.ManyToManyField(conf_settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='CompanyMembership')
    ...

class CompanyMembership(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Dm_Company)
    user = models.ForeignKey(conf_settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    is_contact = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The difficulty with this model is that you need to write logic to prevent more than one CompanyMember from being set as `is_contact`. However, it does structure your data model such that there's no way for the company_contact to reference a user in a different company.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to filter the `company_contact` queryset in the way you describe. An alternative is to add the following to your model:

```
def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
    super().clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
    if not self.company_members.exists(id=self.company_contact_id):
        raise ValidationError('contact is not member')
```

That will prevent a contact being selected that is not a member